# How to generate mixed frequency sinewave using STM32F4 DAC?

Tags: signal-processing, stm32, dac, sine-wave

I am using STM32F4 Discovery board. I have generated a 10Hz sine wave using DAC Channel1.

As per STM's Application note, the sine wave generation should be done as follows:

[image]

And it can be used to produce desired frequency using following formula:

[image]

This is my simple function which populates 100 Samples. Since I used fTimerTRGO = 1kHz, fSinewave is correctly coming as 1k/100 = 10Hz

```
Appl_getSineVal();
HAL_DAC_Start_DMA(&hdac, DAC_CHANNEL_1, (uint32_t*)Appl_u16SineValue, 100, DAC_ALIGN_12B_R);
.
.
.
.
void Appl_getSineVal(void)
{
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<100; i+=1){
        Appl_u16SineValue[i] = ((sin(i*2*PI/100) + 1)*(4096/2));
    }
}
```

Now I want to super impose another sine wave of frequency 5Hz in addition to this on the same channel to get a mixed frequency signal. I need help how to solve this.

I tried by populating Appl_u16SineValue[] array with different sine values, but those attempts doesnot worth mentioning here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to combine two sine waves, just add them:

```
sin(...) + sin(...)
```

Since the sum is in the range [-2...2] (instead of [-1...1]), it needs to be scaled. Otherwise it would exceed the DAC range:

```
0.5 * sin(...) + 0.5 * sin(...)
```

Now it can be adapted to the DAC integer range as before:

```
(0.5 * sin(...) + 0.5 * sin(...) + 1) * (4096 / 2)
```

Instead of the gain 0.5 and 0.5, it's also possible to choose other gains, e.g. 0.3 and 0.7. They just need to add up to 1.0.

**Update**

For your specific case with a 10Hz and a 5Hz sine wave, the code would look like so:

```
for (uint8_t i=0; i < 200; i++) {
    mixed[i] = (0.5 * sin(i * 2*PI / 100) + 0.5 * sin(i * 2*PI / 200) + 1) * (4096 / 2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But this method helps in mixing Amplitudes of two sinewave samples. But I want to mix frequencies.
Frequency is defined / decided as ftimer/ns. But I am unable to create an array for DAC that has same ns, but with mixed frequcies. Hope you get my issue.

Comment: In the time domain, mixing two frequencies is mixing two sine wave amplitudes. I've added how the resulting code with different formulas within the *sin* function looks like.

Comment: The updated code works! This is something so simple yet could not have come-up on my own until I see and understand it. Thanks a lot. 

For others who are trying to do the same, the waveform look like this :
https://imgur.com/a/UZh7Xxw